# Starting weblogic domain in 32 bit jdk

Tags: weblogic

I am using weblogic 10.3 on a 64 bit sparc machine. 
The domains on this installation run on a 64 bit jdk version.

I would like to run one domain using a 32 bit jdk version while the rest of the domains run on 64 bit jdk.

Is this possible? If yes, what change needs to be made on the setDomainEnv.sh file ?

**Further update**

Set domain does not have a -d64 for the weblogic 10.3.5 version. There is a JAVA_USE_BIT variable which is set to 64 bit in the commonEnv.sh. But that is changed, all domain will start in 32 bit jdk.

So there has to be some other way to start only once domain in 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Check your setDomainEnv.sh for a `-d64` flag passed into the USER_MEM_ARGS or JAVA_OPTIONS

This is to use a 64-bit JDK, try removing that flag for 32-bit.
check the same in the `startWeblogic` sh

But I'm not sure everything will work okay, there are some reported errors on various forums

Comment: Set domain does not have a -d64 for the weblogic 10.3.5 version. There is a JAVA_USE_BIT variable which is set to 64 bit in the commonEnv.sh. But that is changed, all domain will start in 32 bit jdk. So there has to be some other way to start only once domain in 32 bit.